# DownloadManager throw android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, android-service, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

DownloadManager throw `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` only on Samsung devices(Android 10).

```
            val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
            val fileName = parseFileName(url)
            request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url))
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
            request.setNotificationVisibility(
                DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED
            ) 
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                fileName
            )
            val dm = activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager?
            dm?.enqueue(request)
```

Stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2098)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderProxy.java:481)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1835)
       at android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:1544)
```

`dm?.enqueue(request)` throw `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Although it can be called in the main thread.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Run any download related stuff in background threads.

Comment: We can run DownloadManager.eneque() in main thread.

Comment: It work on other devices.

Comment: @RageTF What is the SDK level for those devices? `Android 5 (Lolipop) -> SDK 22, Android 6 (Marshmallow) -> SDK 23, ..`. By the way, you should use `@<username>` to annotate a user, so that user gets notify.

Comment: @Darkman Thanks. Android 10 -> SDK 29

Comment: @RageTF Have you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on my Samsung devices (s9 and a71). I use
`.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)`
instead of
`.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)`
And it works on Samsung devices also.

Answer (score 1):

Just got this error, and it turns out: **I didn't include the File Extension!!**

Ex: `xxx.png`

Answer (score 0):

@RageTF Don't know why you thank me but a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. This is only thrown for applications targeting the **Honeycomb SDK 11** or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it’s heavily discouraged. So if you are attempting to perform any of these operations on the **UI thread**, you must wrap them in a **worker thread**. The majority of the time the error stems from placing **expensive operations** directly on the **UI thread**. To ensure you don’t **disrupt** the user experience, it is very important to execute Socket connections, HTTP requests, file downloads, and other long-term operations on a separate `Thread` class.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but I try to download image via DownloadManager. And DownloadManager.eneque() throw NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: The download manager will conduct the download in the background.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager